# XSS and Applet/Param HTML Keywords

Tags: java, html, applet, xss

I have a Web application and have run a XSS scan on it and it reports that one of my pages that has a Java applet in it could potentially be open to XSS.

The test managed to assign a javascript alert box to the following HTML code:

```
<param name='id' value='' onMouseOver=alert(40041)>
```

My question is - Is this a valid test?  Will doing any XSS javascript manipulation on Param objects cause any real world issue? I don't think a MouseOver on a param object will do anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid test and it may be a serious vulnerability.

If contents of `value` was not escaped then the attacker could close the tag and add any other script.

Even if `<>` are escaped/stripped, but quotes aren't, it may still be exploitable: attacker could attach event handlers like `onload` and `onerror`. In modern browsers every element can be made visible (e.g. even `<head>`), so `style` could make `<param>` hoverable too.

It's quite simple to protect against XSS like this. When generating attributes always use quotes and in the value change:

- `&` to `&amp;`
- `<` to `&lt;`,
- `'` to `&x39;`
- and `"` to `&quot;`.

and you won't have to worry what bad things could happen with hijacked `<param>`.

Comment: While interesting, this doesn't exactly answer the question.